# print lines between 2 recurring words of text

Tags: python, regex

Previous question Duplicated due to not getting the exact duplicate.This is an different question and i searched entire Web for this question!

I am a newbie and joined this site to solve this problem,I want to print some specific lines between 2 words of a text file.

text file

```
....

accounts
Bank
Credit
 good value
 money
Amount  
Amount
```

I need to print the lines between "Credit" and "Amount".Problem:Here it has two "Amount",so I can't solve it.

Expected output:

```
good value
money
```

Please help!Answers will be appreciated!

Coding:
import re

result = []

```
with open("acc.txt", "r") as f:
    a = [x.rstrip() for x in f]
    # store its index
    for item in a:
        if item.startswith("Credit"): # same as your re check
            break
    ind = a.index(item) #here it produces index no./line no.
    result.extend(a[ind:])
        if item.startswith("Amount"): 
            break
    ind = a.index(item) #here it produces index no./line no.
    result.extend(a[:ind])
for item in result:
  print item
```

Comment: Did you seriously just repost this?

Comment: I think you are going to have a hard time getting answers out of SO for this. You should look up tutorials on Python for string parsing and regex.

Comment: @miindlek nearly a fortnight, across nine accounts: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24849562/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe is a hunter on the stack, the bane of all reposters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below code,

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = """accounts
... Bank
... Credit
...  good value
...  money
... Amount  
... Amount"""
>>> m = regex.findall(r'(?s)(?<=Credit\s*\b).*?(?=Amount)', s)
>>> for i in m:
...     print i
... 

 good value
 money
```