# create python list on the fly

Tags: list, python-2.7, for-loop

I am trying to create python list on the fly. I have two files, one has keys an other file have keys and values.

key file: File1:

```
abc_506        30319
abc_506        30319
abc_506        30319
abc_506        30319
abc_506        30319
abc_506        30319
abc_506        30319
abc_506        30319
abc_506        30319
abc_506        105152
abc_506        105152
abc_506        105152
abc_506        105152
abc_506        105152 
abc_506        56789
abc_506        56789
```

File2:

```
abc_506        30319    SomeInfo
abc_506        30319    SomeInfo
abc_506        30319    SomeInfo
abc_506        30319    SomeInfo
abc_506        30319    SomeInfo
abc_506        30319    SomeInfo
abc_506        30319    SomeInfo
abc_506        30319    SomeInfo
abc_506        30319    SomeInfo
abc_506        105152   otherInfo
abc_506        105152   otherInfo
abc_506        105152   otherInfo
abc_506        105152   otherInfo
abc_506        105152   otherInfo
```

I am trying to match the data from file1 to file2 to create a list like below.  If there are extra keys in file1..the list should contain "NNNNNNNNN" for that key.

```
list1=[['someInfo','someInfo','someInfo','someInfo','someInfo','someInfo','someInfo','someInfo','someInfo'],['OtherInfo','OtherInfo','OtherInfo','OtherInfo','OtherInfo'],["NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN"]]
```

What I am trying is:

import motility

```
File1=open("File1",'r')
File2=open("File2",'r')

File1_dict = {}

list2=[]

for line in File1:
        line=line.strip()
        File1_dict[line]=1


for keys in File1_dict.keys():
        list1=[]
        for line in File2:
                fields=line.split("\t")
                key=fields[0]+"\t"+fields[1]
                if key==keys:
                    list1.append(fields[2])
                else:
                    list1.append("NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN")
        list2.append(list1)

print list2
```

But its not working I am expecting list2 contains list of list

Comment: What do you need file 1 and the first two columns of file 2 for? Can't see that from your desired output.

Comment: sorry. I have edited. I would like to use file1 as key to search against file2 and create a list of column 3 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are asking. As I understand the question, you want to group the elements in the third column in file 2 by the keys in file 1. So, if the key (the first two columns from file 2) is in file 1, then add column 3 to that group. There could also be lines in file 2 with no corresponding line in file 1 and the values in the third column are not all the same, Otherwise this would be much simper...

Try something like this:

```
with open("File1") as file1:
    # create dict with all the keys from file 1
    file1_dict = dict((line.strip(), []) for line in file1)

    with open("File2") as file2:
        # read lines from file 2
        for line2 in map(str.strip, file2):
            # split into key from file1 and value
            key, val = line2.rsplit("\t", 1)
            # if key is in file1        
            if key in file1_dict:
                file1_dict[key].append(val)

    print file1_dict
```

Output:

```
{'abc_506\t105152': ['otherInfo', 'otherInfo', 'otherInfo', 'otherInfo', 'otherInfo'],
 'abc_506\t30319': ['SomeInfo', 'SomeInfo', 'SomeInfo', 'SomeInfo', 'SomeInfo', 'SomeInfo', 'SomeInfo', 'SomeInfo', 'SomeInfo']}
```

Some pointers:

- you can create the `file1_dict` in just one line using a dictionary comprehension
- make a habit of using `with` for opening files, as this will automatically close them afterwards
- file objects are iterators, so once you looped them once, they are exhausted (see below)
- instead of looping `file2` for each item in `file1_dict`, loop it just once and check whether that key is in the dict; this will also be faster, as dict lookup is O(1)
- if you really want just the values, without the keys, use `file1_dict.values()`

The problem with your code is related to files being iterators: You try to iterate over the `File2` iterator for each key in `file1_dict`, but after the first key, the iterator will be exhausted (see [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24849595/1639625) for more explanation), so you only get the matching lines for the first key in the dict.

You could use `readlines` to read all the lines to a list and then iterate this list, or reset the file with `seek(0)`, or open a new `File2` iterator for each key, but the easiest way is to iterate `File2` just once, checking whether the lines are in the `file1_dict` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to know why my code is not working..Because sometimes, the key file contains extra keys which may not be present in file2...in which cae I would like to print Junk value...

Comment: @gthmgeeky In case my answer and the added paragraph at the end are not clear, please be more specific what's the actual problem. How should this "junk value" look like? Please update your question with a comprehensive, representative example of those two input files and the expected output.

Comment: I have edited. The extra key in file1.. "abc_506\t56789"..should get "NNNNNNN".

{'abc_506\t105152': ['otherInfo', 'otherInfo', 'otherInfo', 'otherInfo', 'otherInfo'],
 'abc_506\t30319': ['SomeInfo', 'SomeInfo', 'SomeInfo', 'SomeInfo', 'SomeInfo', 'SomeInfo', 'SomeInfo', 'SomeInfo', 'SomeInfo'],'abc_506\t56789':['NNNNNNNNNNNNNN']}

Comment: @gthmgeeky What's wrong with just having the empty list `[]` as the "junk value" for items from file 1 that have no correspondence in file 2?

Comment: This is a piece of code I am writing. But this should be fine. Today I learnt an important lesson about "file objects are iterators and they gets exhausted once looped". This is not the case in Perl and I have been hitting my head about that part....Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If the first two columns are always the same in the two files, why do you need file1?
How would you like to match the data from file1 to file2?

Without fully understanding your question, I can't really answer it, but here's a way
to get the data from file2 (from column 3), and group it by equal values.

```
from itertools import groupby

file2 = open("file2.txt", "r")
flat_list = map(get_third_column, file2.readlines())
grouped_list = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(flat_list)]

def get_third_column(line):
    return line.split()[2]
```

Comment: there will some extra keys in file1,,..which may not be present in file2