# Iterate Nested Loops

Tags: list, python-2.7, for-loop, dictionary, nested-loops

I have a `list` and a `dict`.

Once I enter the nested `for` loop, the first `for` loop does not continue to iterate through the values. This only allows me to iterate through once, whether my `if` statements succeed or not.

```
for OldRecord in StripOldList:
    OldSplitRec = OldRecord.split('_')
    value1 = OldSplitRec[1]
    value2 = OldSplitRec[2]
    value3 = OldSplitRec[3]
    value3 = OldSplitRec[4]
    value3 = OldSplitRec[5]

    diffdict = {}
    for SomeRec in DiffSplitText:
        key1, key2, key3, key4, key5= SomeRec.strip().split('_')
        FinalLabel = key1+"_"+key2+"_"+key3+"_"+key4+"_"key5+"_"+key6
        diffdict[key1,key2,key3,key4,key5.strip()] = FinalLabel

        IsNewEdition = True
        IsNewVersion =  True
        IsNewFileType = True

        if (value1 == key1 and value2 == key2):
           IsNewFileType = False

           if (value3 >= key3):
               IsNewEdition = False

           if (value5 >= key5):
               IsNewVersion = False
        if (IsNewFileType == True):
           print "No Match"
        elif (IsNewEdiion == True):
           print  "Found new edition"
           link1.write(SomeRec)
        elif (IsNewVersion == True):
           print "Found new version"
           link2.write(SomeRec)
```

Then, I am comparing for example `value1` with `key1`, or `value5` with `key6`.  My `if` statements work, but only do it once so this is the only part I'm concerned about.

An example of the files it's read looking like:

```
Ex_299_Jabba_1993_09_20150805
```

So if the old list has:

```
Ex_299_Jabba_1993_09_20130805
Ex_298_Jabba_1993_09_20130805
Ex_297_Jabba_1993_09_20130805
```

and the new dictionary has:

```
Ex_299_Jabba_1993_09_20140805
Ex_298_Jabba_1994_09_20130805
Ex_297_Jabba_1993_09_20130805
```

it should recognize the updated file names in the dictionary and write them to the correct location (emphasized with `**`).

```
Ex_299_Jabba_1993_09_**20140805**
Ex_298_Jabba_**1994**_09_20130805
```

Comment: Show us working, complete example code.

Comment: What is `DiffSplitText`? If you want to compare all possible pairs, look at [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Comment: DiffSplitText is just the text file it is pulling the filenames from

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> DiffSplitText is just the text file it is pulling the filenames from

This is the problem: If `DiffSplitText` is a `file` object, it is an iterator. Your nested loop

```
for SomeRec in DiffSplitText:
```

iterates all the lines in the file, but after the first iteration, [that file iterator is exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5187457/1639625)!

If you want to read the lines again, you have to reset the iterator, using `DiffSplitText.seek(0)` in each iteration of the outer loop.