# Python double loop for dict

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, iteration

I have csv file like this:

```
fio,username,otdel
Andrey,a.andrey,it
Vlad,v.vlad,support
Love,l.love,bill
Vasy,v.pupkin,main
```

and I need to mix it like this

```
User,fio2,username2,otdel2
a.andrey,Vlad,v.vlad,support
a.andrey,Love,l.love,bill
a.andrey,Vasy,v.pupkin,main
v.vlad,Andrey,a.andrey,it
v.vlad,Love,l.love,bill
v.vlad,Vasy,v.pupkin,main
.....
```

i made this code:

```
import csv
def mixusr(filecsv):
    csvfile = csv.DictReader(open(filecsv), delimiter=",")
    outfile = csv.writer(open('pile.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',')
    outfile.writerow(['User', 'fio2', 'username2', 'otdel2'])
    for key in csvfile:
        outfile.writerow([key['username'], key['fio'], key['username'], key['otdel']])
        for xkey in csvfile:
            outfile.writerow([key['username'], xkey['fio'], xkey['username'], xkey['otdel']])


mixusr('list.csv')
```

But it stop iteration , and output is

```
User,fio2,username2,otdel2
v.vlad,Vlad,v.vlad,support
v.vlad,Andrey,a.andrey,it
v.vlad,Love,l.love,bill
v.vlad,Vasy,v.pupkin,main
```

What i'am doing wrong.
when i do this

```
def mixusr(filecsv):
    csvfile = csv.DictReader(open(filecsv), delimiter=",")
    **csvfile2 = csv.DictReader(open(filecsv), delimiter=",")**
    outfile = csv.writer(open('pile.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',')
    outfile.writerow(['User', 'fio2', 'username2', 'otdel2'])
    for key in csvfile:
        outfile.writerow([key['username'], key['fio'], key['username'], key['otdel']])
        for xkey in **csvfile2**:
            outfile.writerow([key['username'], xkey['fio'], xkey['username'], xkey['otdel']])
```

i get this: the second iteration not working, and i don't know anything what wrong !!HELP

```
User,fio2,username2,otdel2
v.vlad,Vlad,v.vlad,support
v.vlad,Vlad,v.vlad,support
v.vlad,Andrey,a.andrey,it
v.vlad,Love,l.love,bill
v.vlad,Vasy,v.pupkin,main
a.andrey,Andrey,a.andrey,it
l.love,Love,l.love,bill
v.pupkin,Vasy,v.pupkin,main
```

Comment: I don't use the `csv` module very often, but I have a feeling that you can only iterate through a csv file once. Attempting to iterate through it a second time will give you zero lines.

Comment: Agreed, problem is using the same reader iterator in both loops. After the first iteration of the inner loop, the iterator is exhausted and the outer loop ends. See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24849562/1639625) for a similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already explained in the comments, the problem is that a [csv reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) is an iterator, thus it will be [exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187457/what-does-it-mean-to-consume-in-python-in-an-iterator) once you have iterated it once, i.e. the outer loop will end after the *first* pass of the inner loop.

To fix this, you could create a new reader in each iteration of the inner loop, but instead I suggest using `itertools.product` to get each combination of users.

```
import csv
import itertools
def mixusr(filecsv):
    csvfile = csv.DictReader(open(filecsv), delimiter=",")
    outfile = csv.writer(open('pile.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',')
    outfile.writerow(['User', 'fio2', 'username2', 'otdel2'])
    for key, xkey in itertools.product(csvfile, repeat=2):
        if key != xkey:
            outfile.writerow([key['username'], xkey['fio'], xkey['username'], xkey['otdel']])
```

Note that you need to call `outfile.writerow` just once; that second call in your code was necessary only because the first item was already consumed by the outer loop. Also, while my version is true to your "how it should look" example, you might instead want to use `itertools.combinations`.