# Lambda Functions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

In the NLTK toolkit, I try to use the lambda function to filter the results.

I have a test_file and a terms_file

What I'm doing is to use the likelihood_ratio in NLTK to rank the multi word terms in the terms_file. But, the input here is the lemma of the multi word terms, so I created a function which extracts from each multi word term its lemma to be introduced afterthat in the lambda function.

so it looks like this

```
text_file = myfile
terms_file= myfile
def lem(file):
    return lemma for each term in the file
```

My problem is here

How can I call this function in the filter, because when I do what following it does not work.

```
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(text_file)
finder.apply_ngram_filter(lambda *w: w not in lem(terms_file))
finder.score_ngrams(BigramAssocMeasures.likelihood_ratio)
print(finder)
```

Also with the iteration does not work

```
   finder.apply_ngram_filter(lambda *w: w not in [x for x in lem(terms_file)])
```

Comment: My guess: The `terms_file` file handle (an iterator) is exhausted after the first call to `lem`. But without more code that's just a wild guess. Try calling the function just once and storing the results in a list. This should also be much faster than reading the file over and over again.

Comment: What is `lem` actually returning? Your code seems to be half real and half pseudocode, which makes it hard to say anything about.

Comment: "is not working" is about the less usefull description of a problem.

Answer (score 2):

(This is sort of a wild guess, but I'm pretty confident that this is the cause of your problem.

Judging from your pseudo-code, the `lem` function operates on a file handle, reading some information from that file. You need to understand that a file handle is an iterator, and it [will be exhausted when iterated once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5187457/1639625). That is, the first call to `lem` works as expected, but then the file is fully read and further calls will yield no results.

Thus, I suggest storing the result of `lem` in a list. This should also be much faster than reading the file again and again. Try something like this:

```
all_lemma = lem(terms_file) # temporary variable holding the result of `lem`
finder.apply_ngram_filter(lambda *w: w not in all_lemma)
```

Your line `finder.apply_ngram_filter(lambda *w: w not in [x for x in lem(terms_file)])` does not work, because while this creates a list from the result of `lem`, it does so each time the `lambda` is executed, so you end up with the same problem.

(Not sure what `apply_ngram_filter` does, so there might be more problems after that.)

---

Update: Judging from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32999541/1639625), it seems like `lem` itself is a generator function. In this case, you have to explicitly convert the results to a list; otherwise you will run into just the same problem when that generator is exhausted.

```
all_lemma = list(lem(terms_file))
```

If the elements yielded by `lem` are hashable, you can also create a `set` instead of a list, i.e. `all_lemma = set(lem(terms_file))`; this will make the lookup in the `filter` much faster.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are saying, `lem(terms_file)` returns a list of lemmas. But what do "lemmas" look like? `apply_ngram_filter()` will only work if each "lemma" is a tuple of exactly two words. If that is indeed the case, then your code should work after you've fixed the file input as suggested by @tobias_k.

Even if your code works, the output of `lem()` should be stored as a set, not a list. Otherwise your code will be abysmally slow.

```
all_lemmas = set(lem(terms_file))
```

But I'm not too sure the above assumptions are right. Why would all lemmas be exactly two words long? I'm guessing that "lemmas" are one word long, and you intended to discard any ngram containing a word that is not in your list. If that's true you need `apply_word_filter()`, not `apply_ngram_filter()`. Note that it expects one argument (a word), so it should be written like this:

```
finder.apply_word_filter(lambda w: w not in all_lemmas)
```