# get a list in a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function in python like this

```
def lemmma(file):
    for i in file:
        yield i
```

This function returns each element in the file

What can I do if I want that the function return a list of elements?

Comment: return `list(file)` or make a list of the result `list(lemma(file))`

Comment: Coming from [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32994939/1639625): Note that even if this function returns a list, it will only return a list the first time it is called. If you call it again, the file handler is exhausted and it will just return an empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def lemmma(file):
    lst=[]
    for i in file:
        lst.append(i)
    return lst
```

Or even better,

```
def lemmma(file):
    return [i for i in file]
```

Or,

```
def lemma(file):
    return list(file)
```

Comment: Or `return list(file)`.

Comment: Oh sorry, how i have missed that?